# Question on definition of Weyl Group in Brian Hall

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I wanted to follow a proof of Brian Hall "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and their Representations" but I'm stuck with Definiton 7.25 of the Weyl group which he gives as the group generated by all reflections $s_\alpha:\mathfrak{h}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ such  $$ s_{\alpha}\cdot H=H-\frac{2\left\langle \alpha,\,H\right\rangle }{\left\langle \alpha,\,\alpha\right\rangle }\alpha, $$
Now I'm quite perplexed on this definition... is it right? Should it be $H_\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$? Isn't $\alpha$ in the dual of the cartan subalgebra?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without access to the book. Is $\alpha\in\mathfrak{h}^*$? If so, is $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ a bilinear form on $\mathfrak{h}^*$ or a pairing $\mathfrak{h}^*\times\mathfrak{h}\to\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, ${\displaystyle \sigma _{\alpha }(\beta ):=\beta -2{\frac {(\alpha ,\beta )}{(\alpha ,\alpha )}}\alpha  .}$

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell, standard notation $\alpha$ is in  $\mathfrak{h}^*$ the problem here is that $H$ is in $\mathfrak{h}$ and the reflection is an action on $\mathfrak{h}$. I just copied the text, please have a look because I'm confused

Comment: It looks like the author is not being careful at all with notation you will need to adjust as necessary to make sense of it: $H=H_\beta$ for some $\beta\in \mathfrak{h}^*$ and $$s_\alpha H_\beta=H_\beta-\frac{2\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle}{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle}H_\alpha.$$

Comment: Incidentally, I would expect to have $s_\alpha H_\beta=H_{s_\alpha(\beta)}$.

Comment: Thank you David, it was the same idea I came up with. If you had posted as a solution I would have accepted